# Recordtype Change Button - Unexpected Token ;

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I must have some syntax error I am missing on this button. Am I missing something? Thanks

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")} 

var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
caseObj.Id = '{!Case.Id}'; 
caseObj.RecordTypeId = '012E0000000NFJO';

var result = sforce.connection.update([caseObj]);

if (result[0].success =='false') (
     alert (result[0].errors.message);
) else (
    location.reload(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change some parens to brackets.

```
if (result[0].success =='false') { 
    alert (result[0].errors.message); 
} else { 
    location.reload(true);
}
```

UPDATE:

You should really use a tool like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to clean up your JavaScript. In addition to making your questions easier for us to read and therefore answer, you may fix some of these bugs yourself!